# Scraping Wiki Page In Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.3

I'm trying to scrape some text from a wiki page specifically [this one.](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Tips%3aBlue-Eyes_White_Dragon)
I'm using BeautifulSoup, or at least trying to...I'm not really experienced with webscraping. Here is my code so far...

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup =BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Tips:Blue-Eyes_White_Dragon').read())

for row in soup('span', {'class' : 'mw-headline'})[0].tbody('tr'):
      tds = row('td')
      print(tds[0].string, tds[1].string, tds[2].string)
```

I'm just trying to get each of the headers (Searchable by, Special Summoned from the hand by, etc) and get each card under each category. Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 3):

If you will inspect the HTML code, you will find:

```
<div class="mw-content-ltr" dir="ltr" id="mw-content-text" lang="en">
 ...
 <h3>
  <span class="mw-headline" id="Searchable_by">
   Searchable by
  </span>
 ...
 </h3>
 <ul>
  <li>
   "
   <a href="/wiki/Summoner%27s_Art" title="Summoner's Art">
    Summoner's Art
   </a>
   "
  </li>
  <li>
   "
   <a href="/wiki/The_White_Stone_of_Legend" title="The White Stone of Legend">
    The White Stone of Legend
   </a>
   "
  ...
  </li>
 </ul>
 ...
<\div>
```

That snippet above shows the fact that:

- a `div` with `id="mw-content-text"` contains the wiki.
- The titles are in `h3` tag's first (and only) `span`.
- A `ul` tag contains the bulleted list.

So in Python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('stack.htm').read()) # I saved the webpage
main_tag = soup.findAll('div',{'id':'mw-content-text'})[0]

headers = main_tag.find_all('h3')
ui_list = main_tag.find_all('ul')
for i in range(len(headers)):
    print(headers[i].span.get_text())
    print('\n -'.join(ui_list[i].get_text().split('\n')))
sections = zip((x.span.get_text() for x in headers), ('\n -'.join(x.get_text().split('\n')) for x in ui_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to find all `<ul>` elements following your headers, then list the links under those to get the cards:

```
for headline in soup('span', {'class' : 'mw-headline'}):
    print(headline.text)
    links = headline.find_next('ul').find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        print('*', link.text)
```

which prints:

```
Searchable by
* Summoner's Art
* The White Stone of Legend
* Deep Diver
Special Summoned from the hand by
* Ancient Rules
* Red-Eyes Darkness Metal Dragon
* King Dragun
* Kaibaman
```

etc.

Comment: This one is perfect! Thank you.